How to quote fzf output as a string?
I created the following function:
function! Meow()
    call fzf#run({'source': "echo \"aaa\nbbb\nccc\n\"", 'sink': 'echom'})
endfunc

My goal was to print the selected text from fzf. Unfortunately, I get an error:
Vim(echomsg):E121: Undefined variable: cccc

How to quote cccc as a string?

I would try:
function! Meow()
    call fzf#run({'source': "echo aaa && echo bbb && echo ccc", 'sink': 'echom'})
endfunc


No, the same error.

Thanks for the feedback. I'm testing on Windows with success. I'll try to test on WSL.
